# Present an UIAlertController with a SpriteKit scene (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uikit

I'm trying to make a SpriteKit app that has a button to go to my website if the user so desires to. I thought it would be a good practice to make an alert (since it's made for iOS 8, I'd use a `UIAlertController`) confirming if they want to be redirected to Safari to see it.

Here's what I have in code for the method to make/present this alert so far:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Go to website" message:@"Would you like to visit DannyDalton.com? This will open Safari." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *yes = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
            [self goToSite];
        }];
        UIAlertAction *no = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){}];
        [alertController addAction:yes];
        [alertController addAction:no];
        [alertController presentViewController:(UIViewController*)self animated:YES completion:nil];
```

My problem is presenting `alertController` onto the view controller, so it pops up. Any suggestions on how to make the `SKView` into a `UIViewController` so that `alertController` can present itself onto the screen? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `NSNotification`.

In the `GameViewController`(containing `SKView`) add a `NSNotification` observer to call the function to show the alert when receiving the notification.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showAlert:", name: "showAlert", object: nil)
     }

    func showAlert(object : AnyObject) {

       // Your alert code.
    }
}
```

Then post this notification from the place where you want to show the alert.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showAlert", object: nil)
```