# Swift3: adding a UIAlertController in a SKView

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, uialertcontroller

## Note:

There are several questions (or resources) already out there in relation to this:

- [App Coda: UIAlertController Swift](http://www.appcoda.com/uialertcontroller-swift-closures-enum/)
- [How would I create a UIAlertView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift)
- [Swift & SpriteKit - How to present alert view in GameScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557344/swift-spritekit-how-to-present-alert-view-in-gamescene)
- [Present an UIAlertController with a SpriteKit scene (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159008/present-an-uialertcontroller-with-a-spritekit-scene-objective-c)
- [Displaying a UIAlertController in GameScene (SpriteKit/Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34367268/displaying-a-uialertcontroller-in-gamescene-spritekit-swift)
- [How to present UIAlertController from SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152621/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-from-skscene)

So I am sorry for adding a similar question. However, I have attempted to implement those solutions without success.

To make this question a bit more concrete than the aforementioned question, let's use the M.W.E. ([Stack Overflow SKSpriteKit](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflow-SKSpriteKit-with-Menu)) presented in two other Swift related questions:

- [Swift: SKSpriteKit, using Storyboards, UIViewController and UIButton to set in game parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41782820/swift-skspritekit-using-storyboards-uiviewcontroller-and-uibutton-to-set-in-g)
- [Swift: returning to Main Menu after condition is met in GameScene using StoryBoards and UIViewControllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790105/swift-returning-to-main-menu-after-condition-is-met-in-gamescene-using-storyboa)

## Context:

In the [M.W.E.](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflow-SKSpriteKit-with-Menu)
there is one main `UIViewController`, `GameViewController` that calls forth the main menu scene, which is an `SKView`. The various custom `SKView`s link cyclicly:

menu -> difficulty -> game -> score -> menu -> etc

I mention this, because in most of the above questions, one must add the `UIAlertController` to the main `UIViewController`. I just want to make sure that only the `GameScene` can present the `UIAlertController` and none of the other scenes.

## Question:

How can I implement a `UIAlertController` callable from only one of the `SKView`s? Some of the previous answers, have only the main `GameViewController` and `GameScene`, and then give the `GameScene` (a  constant in the `GameViewController`) a reference to the `GameViewController`. Since in this code, the `GameScene` isn't accessed until much later, how can this be achieved (ideally without propagating a reference to the `GameViewController` through the various `SKView`s.

Please use the [M.W.E.](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflow-SKSpriteKit-with-Menu) when answering this question.

## Goal:

In another related question,
[Swift3: UISwipeGestureRecognizer in only one of putatively many SKViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41822340/swift3-uiswipegesturerecognizer-in-only-one-of-putatively-many-skviews), it posed as to how to implement a `UIGestureRecognizer` for one `SKView`. Ideally, the `UIAlertController` would be presented following that action - as sort of an in game menu.

## Minimum Working Example

[StackOverflow SKSpriteKit](https://github.com/SumNeuron/StackOverflow-SKSpriteKit-with-Menu)

Comment: I think it's been pointed out to you before, but let me make it very clear: SpriteKit and UIKit don't play well together. If you can do it all in SpriteKit, you'll have a lot easier way through this and all subsequent problems. Put another way, your desire to use storyboards AND SpriteKit is your biggest source of problems. Nobody has, to my knowledge, found a happy way to work this way.

Comment: Put another way: SpriteKit and GameplayKit are designed to work together, explicitly. And that's not fun, nor well explained or articulated, and hardly used. Expecting two frameworks at odds with each other (SKScene vs UIViewControllers) to find happy ways to play together is asking a lot of the frameworks that they simply don't seem to have been designed to do. They're not happy campers.

Comment: @Confused the M.W.E. no longer uses UIKit or storyboards for handling the menus. If you have a better way of implementing a pop-up pause-menu, then I am eager to learn from you

Comment: @SumNeuron Upvoted you for your improving to make questions, well done. Minimum working example is the best thing you can put in your questions, this helping a lot, that's great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIAlert` is an `UIKit` element, so you can easily present where do you want in your `SKScene` take references from your view with few code.. 
In other words you can access to the main `window` that display your app’s content, then use the `rootViewController` that provides the content view of the window.

Code sample:

```
if sprite.contains(touchLocation) {
            print("You tapped the blue sprite")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { action in
                // Handle when button is clicked
            }
            alert.addAction(action)
            if let vc = self.scene?.view?.window?.rootViewController {
               vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a long question. Do you want to show a UIAlertController in SKScenes? There is no need to reference the GameViewController from your SKScenes, just show the alerts on the root view controller.

So to present directly from one of your SKScenes you can say this

```
 view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(YOURALERTCONTROLLER, animated: true)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ill have to recreate them, I was just trying whatever I could find on the forums. This was one suggestion... Perhaps you could demo on the M.W.E

Comment: That MWE thing is a simple SpriteKit project. To show a UIAlertController for example in GameScene.swift you create it at usual and than present it like in my answer.